# objectObject problem related to array of parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object

I apologize in advance for if I'm not using the right terminology.

Basically I'm facing a problem with object `filters` in getStats within this function below.

```
const handleRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
  getFruitList();
  getStats({ type: tab ? "Seedless" : "Seed", filters });
}, [tab, getFruitList, getStats], filters);
```

The response I aimed to get after calling handleRefresh goes something like

```
type: Seed
color: Red
shape: Round
```

But instead I'm getting this

```
type: Seed
filters: [object Object]
```

I tried to use JSON.stringify and toString() but it does not work.

Any advise on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you create a demo on a codepen?

Comment: can you share the entire code, the one above doesnt clear anything